# TCPDF: Enlarge/Shrink Page Size AFTER Creation

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am creating photo books with tcpdf - works great. The challenge I have: The final size of the pages is only known once I have created all pages. What I need to do is once I have created all pages: Enlarge the page left or right (depending on if it is the left or the right page of the book). Alternatively, I could make a larger-than-needed page and the cut them off on the left or right hand side. How would I do that - and I would like to keep the background color, which I "painted" on the original page using $pdf->Rect(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight(), 'F', $coverBackground).

Comment: Do you have an example of the elements you are adding to the pages? There may be a way to calculate the layout before calling the TCPDF methods.

Comment: There is one text box centered on the first two pages. Then 4-6 images per page in 2-3 colums. No headers or footers. The more pages I have, the wider these need to be as they are bound to a book on the inner side of the pages later on once printed. Therefore the width of the pages varies a bit.

Comment: Are you calling the `AddPage()` method to create each page of the PDF?

Comment: Yes I do. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. Please let me know if I misunderstood the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Are you using pure TCPDF to create the PDF or are you using an HTML template and so writeHTML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a method that will allow you to resize pages after they are created. From my understanding of your application, the page margins and size are only dependent on their page number or position in the document. Therefore, page size and margins can be calculated by simply knowing the total pages that will be in the document. This allows them to be set before each page is created.

The following example includes an `addCustomPage()` function that can be called in place of `AddPage()`. It calculates margins and size of each page based on the current page number and the total pages in the document. The code for calculating margins will need to be modified or replaced to fit your requirements. It currently assumes pages at the outside of the book will require a wider page size and inner margin. The example should run inside the TCPDF examples directory.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Add page and margins based on current page number of a bound book.
 *
 * Additional margins alternate left and right for two-sided printing. Inside
 * margins and page sizes are larger towards the outside of the book.
 *
 * @param $pdf (object) an instance of TCPDF class for document
 * @param $totalPages (integer) total number of pages in document
 */

function addCustomPage($pdf, $totalPages) {
    $basePageSize = array(210, 294); // Size of page in mm, including margins.
    $pageIndex = $pdf->getPage();

    // Example for calculating margins based on current page number. This is a
    // very simple example that will need to be adjusted for your layout.

    $addToMargin = 0.3;
    if ($pageIndex < $totalPages / 2) {
        $addToMargin*= ($totalPages / 2 - $pageIndex);
    }
    else {
        $addToMargin*= $pageIndex - $totalPages / 2;
    }

    // Add additional margin to left for even pages starting at 0. Right for odd.

    if ($pageIndex % 2 == 0) {
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin(10 + $addToMargin);
        $pdf->SetRightMargin(10);
    }
    else {
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin(10);
        $pdf->SetRightMargin(10 + $addToMargin);
    }

    // Create page with margin added to width

    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($basePageSize[0] + $addToMargin, $basePageSize[1]) , true);
}

require_once ('tcpdf_include.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);

// Generate 50 example pages with background

for ($p = 0; $p < 50; $p++) {
    addCustomPage($pdf, 50);
    $pdf->Rect($pdf->getX() , $pdf->getY() , 190, 274, 'DF', '', array(241, 248, 255));
}

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes i could add custom posts but the challenge still is that i do not know how many pages will be on each page upfront (portrait or landscape, different aspect ratios...). I therefore place one after the other and know only after i have places the last image hour many pages will be filled. I would then have to adjust the page size for all of the book.  If all else fails u wolf have to produce it in two runs but i would like to avoid that.

Comment: @mercator Sounds like an interesting project. I don't completely understand how every part of TCPDF works, however, I believe it may generate the pages as you are adding new page elements (`var_dump($pdf)` is interesting). This is why I don't think page modification is a possibility.

Comment: @mercator To increase efficiency and avoid duplicating work you could use a flow similar to what is used by Reportlab Platypus in Python. First, generate the PDF as you normally would, but add the method names and arguments to an `array` instead of calling the TCPDF methods. You will now know the number of pages and have a very modifiable representation of your PDF.  To generate the PDF iterate over the array of page elements calling the appropriate methods.